# What does your team do to stand out?

Tags: performance, lead

Where I work, we have small teams of 2 - 5 people.  As a dev lead, what are some things that you've implemented which makes your team stand out from the others?  Meaning, it makes the others teams say, "that's cool" or "why didn't we think of that".  Just some thinking out of the box that made your team extremely efficient.

Comment: This should be Community wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automated unit testing and an automated build system (like CruiseControl)

Answer (score 2):

Hawaiian shirt day

Comment: If that is your mayor selling point you are probably in the wrong business :P

Comment: It wasn't a serious answer - tongue is planted firmly in cheek. Please watch Office Space and come back when your sense of humour has been adjusted accordingly. :)

Comment: Personally I would say that my sense of humor would have to be adjusted accordingly *before* I could watch Office Space (US). :)

Comment: Peter, are you confusing office space with "the office"?. There is no "office space (US)..
If you are in IT and have not seen this film, you need something adjusted!

Comment: Peter G, You are right.  I was confusing The Office with Office Space.  But After refreshing my memory via IMDB my comments still stand.  I have seen at least part of it and think its lame.  But then again I am not a USAian, so my sense of humor is rather more well defined ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why compete with other teams, the company goal should be a common one.

We roughly have two teams (one working on the 'off the shelf' product and one working for tailor made solutions). But we are used to help each other alot. And in my opinion that is the way it should be.

Comment: I agree. Teams should look at ways to decrease the animosity between them, rather than increase it. However, a little competition can be a good motivation to producing quality product, if used judiciously.

Comment: In large organizations there is competition for talent.  If you ignore this, you find yourself regressing to the mean.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost -- we get things done on time that meet the done criteria. That's the best thing to do, in my opinion :)

Comment: Most teams here get things done on time so I'm looking for an edge.

Answer (score 0):

We're currently doing unit and functional test automated with CC.NET.  QA loves us for it.  But, I'm looking for things such as that.

Answer (score 0):

Do in-company presentations on general topics that the other teams might be interested in, but are not directly related to their work (otherwise they are supposed to know more than you about those issues).

Volunteer to do inside projects that benefit everyone. (e.g. Stylecop introduction into the codebase, geek lunch every week, and similar)

Comment: This works for team members inclined to do so.  For the others, it is actually a deterrent.  Constant peer pressure to make a presentation when your are an ace developer, but getting in front of people to talk is not your thing really upsets a team's balance.  I would allow it, but not require it.

Answer (score 0):

We standardize only the build process.  We don't make our SKILLED developers use skills that are dictated to them.  We let them code however they want, with an editor and command line, with an IDE, with a hammer and chisel if they want.  They are only constrained by the build process.  Everyone is subject to the same build, in our case an ant script.

Developers like and perform in our group because of the freedom.  Other groups who constrain their developers can't understand how we do it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont agree that its a company Goal. Because finally each person is looking for his or her own self.
Its important for a team to stand out. Reason being manyfold.
To stand out the team must be able to present themselves and the team lead has to take the responsibility. Its not enough to develop good code these days but also to be able to present it

Answer (score -1):

Write good code?

---

**Edit**: Of course this is totally wrong, the actual answer should be:

> Write bad code.

Comment: You can write good code on a bad team.

Comment: Yeah, but it gets a little messy if they move.